# Tag request: [directive]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, asking-questions, questions

I've asked 2 questions[[1](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45703/)][[2](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45913/)] about a directive here. Those are improperly tagged as [regulation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regulation), simply because that comes closest and there is no [directive](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directive) yet.

Could [directive](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directive) be created so I can properly tag my questions?

According to the Consolidated version fo the treaty on the functioning of the European Union, part six, chapter 2, section 1, article 288:

> A **regulation** shall have general application. It shall be binding in its entirety and directly applicable in all Member States.
>
> A **directive** shall be binding, as to the result to be achieved, upon each Member State to which it is addressed, but shall leave to the national authorities the choice of form and methods.